# lodash and immutable which is the best way to compare two objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I follow `lodash` and `immutable` to compare two objects property value.

**lodash**

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var foo = {1: 2};
var bar = {1: 2};
_.isEqual(foo, bar);
```

**immutable**

```
var Immutable = require('immutable');

var foo = {1: 2};
var bar = {1: 2};

map1 = Immutable.Map(foo);
map2 = Immutable.Map(bar);

map1.equals(map2);
```

all above code works well, but I don't know which is more faster way to check objects' property value.

thanks for your time.

regards.

Comment: There is a handy tool for working these things out ;) https://jsperf.com/

Comment: immutable would be faster to compare, much slower to init...